# BBP algorithm get nth digit of PI?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I am trying to turn the [BBP Formula (*Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe*)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BBPFormula.html) in to C# code, it is digit extraction of pi in base 16 (*spigot algorithm*), the idea is give the input of what index/decimal place you want of pi then get that single digit. Let's say I want the digit that are at the decimal place/index 40000 (in base 16) without having to calculate pi with 40000 decimals because I don't care about the other digits.

Anyhow here is the math formula, (*doesn't look like it should be to much code?* )

[image]

Can't say I understand 100% what the formal mean, if I did I probably be able to make it in to code, but from my understanding looking at it.

**Is this correct?**

**pseudo code**

> Pi = SUM = (for int n = 0; n < infinity;n++) {   SUM += ((4/((8*n)+1))
>   - (2/((8*n)+4)) - (1/((8*n)+5)) - (1/((8*n)+6))*((1/16)^n)) }

Capital sigma basically is like a "for loop" to sum sequences together?
example
[image]

and in C# code:

```
static int CapSigma(int _start, int _end)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int n = _start; n <= _end; n++)
    {
        sum += n; 
    }
    return (sum);
}
```

**Code so far** *(not working)*:

```
static int BBPpi(int _precision)
{
    int pi = 0;
    for(int n = 0; n < _precision; n++)
    {
        pi += ((16 ^ -n) * (4 / (8 * n + 1) - 2 / (8 * n + 4) - 1 / (8 * n + 5) - 1 / (8 * n + 6)));
    }
    return (pi);
}
```

I'm not sure how to make it in to actual code also if my pseudo code math is correct?

How to sum 0 to infinity? Can't do it in a for loop and also where in the formula is the part ("input") that specify what nth (index) digit you want to get out? is it the start n (n = 0)? so too get digit 40000 would be n =40000?

Comment: Converting that formula into a working algorithm requires an understanding of the mathematics involved. No, you cannot plug in a value for `n` and get the digits; the formula has to be transformed first. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) has some of the details, but no full working algorithm; David Bailey (yes, of the formula) has some [working code in C](http://www.experimentalmath.info/bbp-codes/), which is not hard to translate to C#.

Comment: `^` is xor in C#, and be aware of integer division.

Comment: I'm not sure it is what is meant by a spigot algorithm, though of course it can be turned into one with a simple loop.  It's more of a random access algorithm, huh?

Comment: You can't find an decimal digit at an arbitrary position based on a string of binary digits at the corresponding position, because to calculate decimal digit n you need to divide by 10^n and modulo 10. 10^n will not be a power of 2 so the answer will depend on most of the binary digits up to that position.

Comment: For computing the nth decimal digit, see [this paper](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/nthdecimaldigit.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast to double :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double sum = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                sum += BBPpi(i);
                Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static double BBPpi(int n)
        {
            double pi = ((16 ^ -n) * (4.0 / (8.0 * (double)n + 1.0) - 2 / (8.0 * (double)n + 4.0) - 1 / (8.0 * (double)n + 5.0) - 1.0 / (8.0 * (double)n + 6.0)));
            return (pi);
        }

    }
```